# Does .NET Core support COM?

Tags: c#, .net-core, com

I'm trying to figure whether we can port our WPF app to .NET Core. One part of the app is using the .NET Full Framework and another part is written in Delphi. At the moment, we are using COM for the transition between the two worlds. With .NET Core, is it possible to marshal objects via COM?

Comment: yes it supports

Comment: It's very easy to test. Create a .NET 3 core console app, and call `Console.WriteLine(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));` for example. It should output `System.__ComObject`. Works on Windows platform only.

Comment: While it is possible, from personal experience (imho): push for porting the delphi to dotnet. Been there, felt like hell. Maintenance nightmare. Maybe it was the Delphi-Teams fault, maybe it was intrinsic. I don't know, but that would be what I would advise from personal experience. (Don't mean to bash delphi. Just using both was giving me hell.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since .Net Core is not windows specific you might won't be able to use COM in other OS. Fortunately you can use in Windows.

More info: 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Jan/22/COM-Object-Access-and-dynamic-in-NET-Core-2x

EDIT:
You need .Net Core 2.x+. It's not supported in 1.x

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .NET Core does support COM references. Do note that this will only ever work on Windows (as will WPF).

You may need to use Visual Studio or msbuild.exe from the Developer Command Prompt to build your project instead of the `dotnet` CLI.

Comment: There are also some limitations. For example if you try to use it from an ASP.NET Core project. I did some digging into it: https://www.mobilize.net/blog/mauricios-blog-redux